# Is it possible to parametrize grabbing URL of a WSO2 DSS 3.2.2 Web data source?

Tags: wso2, datasource, wso2-data-services-server

I’d like to use WSO2 DSS 3.2.2 to integrate a Web based data source.

The problem is, that the URL to be grabbed depends on the users input (i. e. something like http://www.mycompany.com/getItem?search=searchterm, where searchterm refers to the user’s input). As to my understanding, user input should be fed into the operation, and then be handed over to the query (the respective configuration appears to be straightforward), before being “executed” on the data source. However, the interface to define the query of a Web data resource suggests there is no possibility to define a respective input mapping (likewise one can do in definition section of query on a RDBMS), and I neither could get any information on the subject in the documentation.

Could someone confirm whether this can be achieved, and if so, point out how it is to be done?